# Can't use library pdf-creator-node to generate file pdf error phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Error: spawn /app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs ENOENT at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:19) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:472:16) at processTicksAndRejections internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn /app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs', path: '/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs', spawnargs: [ '--local-url-access=false', '/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/scripts/pdf_a4_portrait.js' ] } You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7) at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11) at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10) at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12) at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15) at Object.fail (/app/libs/response.js:51:26) at /app/routes/pdf.js:25:14 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7) at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11) at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10) at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12) at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15) at Object.fail (/app/libs/response.js:51:26) at /app/routes/pdf.js:25:14 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)